# Flat metrics on twisted torus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, torus

I think I figured out how to induce a flat metric on a 2-torus, by defining a parallelogram in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with base of length $\lambda$ along the x axis, and top left corner of coordinates $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$, identifying the opposite sides, and inducing the flat metric of $\mathbb{R}^2$ on it. I can define new coordinates as follows:
$$
x = \lambda u + \tau_1 v \,, \qquad y = \tau_2 v\,,
$$
and the coordinates $(u,v)$ cover the whole parallelogram when they vary within $(0,1)\times(0,1)$. If we make $u$ and $v$ periodic with period 1, we correctly match the gluing conditions for the sides of the parallelogram.
The induced flat metric is then:
$$
ds^2 = (\lambda du + \tau_1 dv)^2 +\tau_2^2 dv^2\,.
$$

My question is : **can I similarly define a flat metric on the twisted torus?**

That is, if the gluing conditions are such that one side is not parallely matched to the opposite one, but it's shifted by a certain amount? I'm not even sure that it admits a flat metric, in this case. If it does, how can I explicitly construct it?

*Edit:* since Ryan said that "twisted torus" is non-standard terminology, here is what I mean with it. It's not a Klein bottle, although a Klein bottle can be obtained with anotherluing rule of this sort.

In the case of a "non-twisted torus" I was identifying them this way: I trace a line parallel to two of the sides of the parallellgram, say AD and BC, and it intersects the remaining two sides AB and CD in two points. These are the points I identify, and by moving the line I find all the pairs of identified points. Now, I want to do the same, but with a non-parallel line. A whole segment of one side AB will still be identified directly with a segment of CD. However, when moving the line, at some stage it will stop intersecting only AB and CD, and it will intersect instead the adjacent AB and AD. In this case I continue the line with the "old rule" (parallely to AB), to the opposite side BC, and then follow it up until it intersects CD, and this is the point I identify with the original point on AB. This way I have identified all points on AB and CD, but they're "shifted" modulo the length of AB. The sides BC and AD are identified with the "old", parallel rule.
If I map my parallelogram to a donut embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the gluing rule I described is like cutting the donut along one circle, rotating ("twisting") the two ends by a certain angle, and gluing them back.

---

Ok, the answer is that I misunderstood the meaning of the parallelogram construction: a torus metric built off a parallelogram *already* describes what I called a "twisted" torus. The amount of skewedness of the parallelogram (in relation to the size of its base) tell you the angle by which you need to "twist" the torus when connecting its two ends.

Comment: Any torus admits a flat metric: Let $X$ be a topological space homeomorphic to the torus $T : = [0,1]\times [0,1] / \sim$, and consider $\phi : X \to T$ a homeomorphism. By identifying each point of $X$ with its image in $T$, one gets a flat metric on $X$.
If what you want is a "nice formula" like what you wrote above, you would need $X$ to have a differential structure a priori, and for the identification of opposite sides to give you a smooth structure you need the opposite sides to be parallel.

Comment: Does "twisted torus" mean Klein bottle?  If so, yes.  If twisted torus means something else, let us know the definition.  "Twisted torus" is non-standard terminology.  These results can be found in many intro differential geometry books.

Comment: I have the feeling that what you are describing as a "twisted torus" based on one parallelogram is simply a "non-twisted torus" based on a slightly different parallelogram. If you are identifying the top and bottom of the original parallelogram such that the bottom-left point is glued to a point in the middle of the top side, the left side of the new parallelogram should simply connect these points. In other words every flat metric on a torus can be obtained as the "non-twisted torus" of an appropriate parallelogram.

Comment: Thanks Timothy (good to see you btw!). Alright if your feeling is correct this dispels all my doubts. So let's say that I have an original parallelogram with modulus $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$, and I decide to identify the points on the top and bottom sides by translating them parallely to a vector which is not parallel to $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$, but rather to $(\tau'_1,\tau_2)$. What you're saying is that this is completely equivalent to just working with a parallelogram with modulus $(\tau'_1,\tau_2)$, right?

Comment: In other words, any torus can be obtained from the rectangular parallelogram by identifying two sides with what I called a "twisting", and this is what people refer to with the construction of the parallelogram.

Comment: Yes, indeed (and good to hear from you too!). On any flat torus you can find two non-parallel simple closed geodesics. Cutting along both gives a parallelogram (without "twisted boundary conditions"). Alternatively, cutting along a single simple closed geodesic and a perpendicular geodesic segment gives a rectangle (with "twisted boundary conditions").